# How to sum multiplied numbers in a for loop in JS?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to sum all numbers in a for loop sequentially, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

```js
var sum;
var score;
for (var i = 2; i < 24; i++)
{
    score = (i*24);
    sum = sum + score;   
}
document.write(sum);
```

I tried parsing variables because I thought it could've been a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give `sum` and `score` an initial value, like `0`, otherwise by default their value is `undefined`. `undefined` + a number yields `NaN`.